# How to convert NSDictionary() with values [PSPDFAnnotationParser class] / [MyCustomAnnotationParser class] into MonoTouch?

Tags: xamarin.ios, nsdictionary

From the documentation of a bound API I'm using:

> overrideClassNames
>
> Use this to use specific subclasses instead of the default PSPDF*
>   classes. e.g. add an entry of [PSPDFAnnotationParser class] /
>   [MyCustomAnnotationParser class] as key/value pair to use the custom
>   subclass. (MyCustomAnnotationParser must be a subclass of
>   PSPDFAnnotationParser) Throws an exception if the overriding class is
>   not a subclass of the overridden class. Note: does not get serialized
>   when saved to disk.
>
> @property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *overrideClassNames

Here's what I tried but doesn't work. Appearently not strings are required but actual types or something. How can I use this in MonoTouch?

```
var oClassDic = new NSMutableDictionary();
oClassDic.Add(new NSString("[PSPDFAnnotationParser class]"), new NSString("[PSPDFKitAnnotationParser class]"));
oDoc.OverrideClassNames = oClassDic;
```

The PSPDFKitAnnotationParser I created like this:

```
[Register("PSPDFKitAnnotationParser")]
    public class PSPDFKitAnnotationParser : PSPDFAnnotationParser
    {
        public PSPDFKitAnnotationParser () : base()
        {
        }

        public PSPDFKitAnnotationParser (PSPDFDocumentProvider provider) : base(provider)
        {
        }

        public PSPDFKitAnnotationParser (IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
        }

        public PSPDFKitAnnotationParser (NSObjectFlag t) : base(t)
        {
        }

        public PSPDFKitAnnotationParser (NSCoder coder) : base(coder)
        {
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MonoTouch's own bindings generally hides the [`class`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and replace them with, the more .NETy, `System.Type`.

However the `MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Class` type exists and can also be used. If the native code expects `class` instances then you should be able to do something like:

```
var oClassDic = new NSMutableDictionary();
oClassDic.Add(new Class("PSPDFAnnotationParser"), new Class("PSPDFKitAnnotationParser"));
oDoc.OverrideClassNames = oClassDic;
```

You might have to tweak this a bit since a `Class` instance is not an `NSObject`, it's a `NativeObject` in MonoTouch, so you might have to go one level deeper and use the `Handle` properties (`IntPtr`) when adding values/keys to your dictionary.

Comment: I had to adjust it a bit: oClassDic.Add(new NSObject( new Class("PSPDFAnnotationParser").Handle ), new NSObject( new Class("PSPDFKitAnnotationParser").Handle ));

Comment: Now I'm facing a native crash. Do I have to keep a reference to the managed object that will be created? If yes: how?

Comment: @Krumelur I do not think `Class` is an `NSObject` (at least it's not binded that way) so wrapping it is not likely to be the answer. You likely need to use the low-level code that `Add` is calling (using the `Handle`) and call it (send the message) directly.

Comment: @poupou maybe a MonoTouch enhancement to NSMutableDictionary.Add() could expose an overload that accepts IntPtr in both params in order to catch those special cases where the desired class does not inherit from NSObject

Comment: To make this clear: if I use it the way I posted, I get called back in my custom class! If the wrapping wouldn't work, this would not happen, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Following @poupou answer <strike>this might work, I have not tested it</strike> this is what you have to do, It Works (TM)

```
var oClassDic = new NSMutableDictionary();
var key = new Class("PSPDFAnnotationParser");
var val = new Class("PSPDFKitAnnotationParser");

IntPtr selSetObjectForKey = Selector.GetHandle ("setObject:forKey:");

Messaging.void_objc_msgSend_IntPtr_IntPtr (oClassDic.Handle, selSetObjectForKey, val.Handle, key.Handle);

oDoc.OverrideClassNames = oClassDic;
```

Selector [setObject: forKey:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableDictionary/setObject%3aforKey%3a) expects an ObjC `id` type on both params

> "id" its just a special type that can hold a pointer to any object you can construct with ObjC

So this should work :)

Hope this helps

Alex